# Add item to ListView (JAVA)

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

I'm trying to get strings from a JSON file and add them to `ListView`.
There isn't any problem in my getting JSON strings codes, my main problem is when I want to add them to a listbox.

I have two classess, one is my `MainActivity.Java` and second is `HandleJSON.Java`.

I'm sure my listview item add code is correct because it works when I use it in my MainActivity class, but I am force to use it in my HandleJSON class and I wonder why it is not working when I write it in my HandleJSON class.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.jsonparser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //public variables
   public  ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
   public  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
   public  ListView lView;
   //private variables
   private String url1 = "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug/35";
   private HandleJSON obj;
   private TextView tView;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResults);
      //lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstTest); //define listview on the form
      //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems); //define adaptor for listview
      //lView.setAdapter(adapter); //set adaptor for listview
      open();
   }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   public void open(){
      obj = new HandleJSON(url1);
      obj.fetchJSON();
      while(obj.parsingComplete);
      tView.setText(obj.getEmail());
   }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

HandleJSON.java :

```
package com.example.jsonparser;

import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;    
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import android.R.integer;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class HandleJSON {
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //public variables
   public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
   //private variables
   private String email = "";
   private MainActivity mainActivity ;
   private String urlString = null;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
   public HandleJSON(String url){
      this.urlString = url;
   }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   public String getEmail(){
      return email;
   }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   public void readAndParseJSON(String in) {
      try {
          JSONObject mainJSON = new JSONObject(in);
          JSONArray bugsArray = mainJSON.getJSONArray("bugs");
          JSONObject firstObject = bugsArray.getJSONObject(0);
          JSONArray cc_detail = firstObject.getJSONArray("cc_detail");
          for(int i=0;i<=cc_detail.length()-1;i++)
          {
              JSONObject currentObject = cc_detail.getJSONObject(i);
              email = currentObject.getString("email");
              mainActivity.listItems.add(email);
              mainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        
          }
          parsingComplete = false;
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   public void fetchJSON(){
      Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         public void run() {
         try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
            String data = convertStreamToString(stream);
            readAndParseJSON(data);
            stream.close();
             } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         }
      });
       thread.start();      
   }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
      java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
      return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
   }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

my LOGCAT :

> 02-02 11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-02 11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.jsonparser/com.example.jsonparser.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 02-02 11:20:01.278:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2294)
>   02-02 11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2348)
>   02-02 11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 02-02
>   11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>   02-02 11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-02
>   11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-02 11:20:01.278:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414) 02-02
>   11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-02
>   11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 02-02 11:20:01.278:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
>   02-02 11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 02-02
>   11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-02 11:20:01.278:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5763): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-02 11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   at
>   com.example.jsonparser.HandleJSON.addMe(HandleJSON.java:64) 02-02
>   11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):     at
>   com.example.jsonparser.HandleJSON.(HandleJSON.java:38) 02-02
>   11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):     at
>   com.example.jsonparser.MainActivity.open(MainActivity.java:42) 02-02
>   11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):     at
>   com.example.jsonparser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
>   02-02 11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 02-02
>   11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>   02-02 11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>   02-02 11:20:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(5763):   ... 11 more

Comment: Specify what you mean with "doesn't work". Does it crash? Shows nothing? Leave the toilet seat up?

Comment: @Marcus haha! That was harsh :p OP please post LogCat

Comment: @Marcus 
 it means when i test my application on my tablet, it crashes :-D

Comment: Then we need the logcat :-) @3Dmajid

Comment: Why do you recreate the adapter inside of addToMyList?
` adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    listItems);
         lView.setAdapter(adapter);` just create it and set it inside the onCreate() and then just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to update the listview.

Comment: @Marcus
excus me, im a new user, i don't know how to send you logcat :-D its so long i can't send it as a comment.

Comment: @FedericoPonzi 
Thanx for you'r help my friend. i didn't know it. of course it can't solve my problem because this code is working on my MainActivity class but doesn't work on another class !!

Comment: If your application crashes, you copy the stacktrace (logcat) output and paste it in your question, formatted as code.

Comment: @Marcus
i did that but its so long and can't be in post. its more than maximum supported character, logcat updates every second !

Comment: it hangs and if i touch on my tablet it crashes !!

Comment: i can give you all of codes if it can helps.

Comment: @3Dmajid Just add the logcat of the error, not the whole logcat output. Filter by error and package.

Comment: What we need here is to see the source of the chrash, I.e. your logcat. Without a stacktrace, we can only guess what is going wrong, which is not optimal. I suggest you find out how to post a real logcat output. Notify me when you've successfully posted your logcat.

Comment: Try this, or other Google hits: http://www.javabeat.net/debug-android-application-logcat/

Comment: @FedericoPonzi 
Thanx for you'r usefull help.

Comment: You are getting exceptions thrown from your database. Seems that the code you've posted is not relevant for the problem

Comment: @Marcus i changed my main post and sent whole codes of my two classes and my new logcat. my main problem is add item to my list in my handleJSON.java class !! when i use       mainActivity.listItems.add(email);mainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in handleJSON.java it gives me errors in catlog but if i use this code in my mainactivity class it hasn't any problem and my program run as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved !!!!!!! 
just define my ListItems as a static variable in my MainActivity :

```
public  static ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
```